# Can Clang output a warning for conversion of double to float?

Tags: c++, gcc, clang, clang++, gcc-warning

This code

```
int main() {
    double d = 3.14;
    float f = d;
}
```

generates a warning with Vision C++ 2015 express:

```
warning C4244: 'initializing': conversion from 'double' to 'float', possible loss of data
```

I would love to also see a warning like this when compiling with Clang (or GCC). Is there a command line option for this? `-Wconversion` does not help here.

Comment: Does `-Wnarrowing` help?

Comment: Which version of gcc / clang are you using? `-Wconversion` raise a warning in gcc 4.4+ and clang 3+.

Comment: Oh boy, I'm sorry. I mixed up two compile bash scripts I was using. So I thought I had `-Wconversion` enabled, but it actually was not. `-Wconversion` does help indeed.

Comment: If you are using c++11 (or newer), you should initialize your value using brackets, e.g. `float f{d};`, since `{}` prevents narrowing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sorry. I mixed up two compile bash scripts I was using. So I thought I had -Wconversion enabled, but it actually was not. **`-Wconversion` does help indeed.**